# Генерация QR-кода программно

Tags: java, qrcode

Есть приложение с полями:

Фамилия
Имя
Отчество
Телефон
Идентификатор

Какие есть варианты реализации генерирования QR-кода в java? Может быть есть библиотеки, или готовые решения? Может где-то описано как это реализовать?

```
public void onQR(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    String fam = "Тестовый";
    String im = "Тест";
    String ot = "Тестович";
    String phone = "tel:89999999999";
    String mail = "mailto:test@test.ru";
    String url = "urlto:https://test.ru";
    String contact = "mecard:" + fam + " " + im + " " + ot + ", г. Тестовск";

    String rez = contact + "," + phone + "," + mail + "," + url;

    try {
        generateQRCodeImage(rez, 350, 350, QRIMG);
    } catch (WriterException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not generate QR Code, WriterException :: " + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not generate QR Code, IOException :: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вариант почитать: https://www.callicoder.com/generate-qr-code-in-java-using-zxing/

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Как вариант структуризации данных, можете использовать JSON

Answer (score 0):

[ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) and [QRGen](https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen).

```
public class CreateQrCode {

public static void main(String... args){
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout =
            QRCode.from("your text")
                    .withSize(250, 250)
                    .to(ImageType.PNG)
                    .stream();

    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("qr-code.png");
        bout.writeTo(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

[Примеры кода](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-qr-codes-java-servlet-qr-code-java/)

Comment: А есть ли библиотеки, куда можно передавать не просто строку, а поля

Имя
Телефон
Сайт
Майл 
и т.д.? Чтобы они были как отдельные поля при сканировании? Надеюсь понятно описала что имею ввиду

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна, посмотрите: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents

Comment: Прочитала статью. попробовала сделать. В своем вопросе добавила метод, в котором это все я делаю и считанный QR-код. Первое там русский язык не отображается, вместо него знаки "?", а второе все идет в одну строчку. Можно ли сделать, чтобы все было в столбик в виде типа Телефон: 89999999999 , E-mail: test@test.ru и  т.д.?

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна кажется, Вы не совсем понимаете суть QR-кодов) Это не красивая табличка для представления данных, а способ их кодирования) Разметьте кодируемую строку так, как Вы хотите (символ новой строки - тоже символ, поэтому он спокойно себе подлежит кодированию), и упакуйте в QR

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что на вход можно подать только 1 строку, разбив ее как мне нужно символами перехода на новую строку и т.д.?

Просто я думала что в QR-код можно отдельно передать поля Телефон, Майл, URL, ИМЯ но видимо нет, только одну строку

Comment: На самом деле вся информация в компьютере представляется одной строкой, иногда очень длинной:)